# Liferay7 service builder dependency

Tags: gradle, liferay, liferay-7

I have created a service builder project (Gradle type) in Liferay7 called `register-user`. There is another service builder project called `register-organization`. I have a situation where one of the service builders depends upon other. However, i am not able to figure out where to put the dependency of one into another. Is there is any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

With each servicebuilder project you create from the template, you get two projects, e.g. `register-user-api` and `register-user-service`. The -service project depends on the -api project and has the dependency noted in its `build.gradle`. Look it up and use exactly the same notation to make any other project depend on `register-user-api`.

The situation changes if both projects do not live in the same workspace: In that case you'll need your own repository (e.g. proxy for Maven Central) where you publish your own modules. Then you can just declare a standard dependency for your modules.

Comment: Hi Olaf,  I have followed your instructions and I will go with your second paragraph. I have my proxy server for maven repository and I am able to publish the modules (both user-registration-api and user-registration-service)and then can resolve dependency to my 'register-organization'. When I tried to deploy the modules. organization-registration-api successfully deployed but not the organization-registration-service. I have seen the logs nothing prints. The console just stuck there.I use Gogo shell command. I see their register-organization-service in Installed phase and api in Active phase.